# glViewport undefined reference

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glfw, glew

### Summary

Compiler `MinGW` OS `Windows 7 x64`

`glViewport()` function gives `Undefined Reference` error

I have tried

1. adding `-lGL` resulted `cannot find -lGL` <-- How do I locate OpenGL dll files ?
2. checked `-Lpath -lglew32 -lglfw3` as if not last linker argument

I may have miscompiled GLEW and/or miscopied GLEW libs as I am not sure if I need libglew32.a and/or libglew32.dll.a files.

I have a folder structure like that

- OpenGL

  - bins

    - glew32.dll
    - glfw3.dll
  - includes

    - GL

      - glew.h
      - glewx.h
      - wglew.h
    - GLFW

      - glfw3.h
      - glfw3native.h
  - libs

    - glfw3.lib

---

### Long Story

Hello experienced programmers. Your humble questioner returns. Today me and my friend decided to start/learn OpenGL. As we follow [this](http://www.learnopengl.com/) tutorial, we have stuck at `glViewport` as it gives `Undefined reference` error. We are working on NetBeans 8.0 C/C++ version. I have double checked the `Makefile` as some sites mentioned `-Lpath -lglew32 -lglfw3` had to be last parameter when compiling. I have tried to ad `-lGL` as linker option, but sadly it won't work.

---

### Code

```
#include <cstdlib>
//GLEW
#include "GL/glew.h"
//GLFW
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "LearnOpenGL", NULL , NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);

    return 0;
}
```

As a side note this is my first time using libraries other than standards.
Well Summary looking much longer than Long Story..

Edit: I do not think this is a duplicate question as I'm asking linking of a specific library, not how can I link something in C++. This is like saying all coding questions are same as all of them involves writing code. Checked the said topic and cannot find any direction about linking opengl32 library.

Comment: Can you get the verbose output from the 'make' command? If compiling via command line, adding VERBOSE=1 to the command will do it

Comment: Unfortunately I am currently using NetBeans generated makefile. But now I am trying to find a way to use VERBOSE=1 in NetBeans makefile.

Comment: Wait, what compiler are you using? I've been assuming GCC on linux but I just noticed you're using .dll's

Comment: I am using MinGW as compiler.

Comment: Ah good. Well adding a `-Wl,--verbose` to the command options should give more information then. That passes `--verbose` to the linker

Comment: It gave me a really huge [output](http://pastebin.com/fnxY6W0z)

Comment: Hmm, nothing obvious to me. Have you downloaded the guy's sample source and tried compiling that? It doesn't have the glViewport call, strangely enough

Comment: I havent noticed that. Even without glViewport() there are errors. -    -`D:\OpenGL\OpenGLTutorial/sample.cpp:21: undefined reference to glClearColor@16'`
 -`D:\OpenGL\OpenGLTutorial/sample.cpp:22: undefined reference to glClear@4'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Windows the OpenGL API interface library is called `opengl32` not `GL`, hence you must link with

```
-lopengl32
```

(note that it's always …32, even on 64 bit systems).

Comment: If adding this does not fix the issue, keep it (you need it either way) and also build `glad.c`. It has these stuff defined.

Comment: @am.rez: `glad.c` is just one of many different OpenGL loader libraries. I'd strongly recommend against mindlessly pulling in and adding 3rd party sources, without actually understanding, what's happening under the hood.

Comment: totally agree. I was using `glad.c` and forgot to add its object in the link process. So I came to help future viewers, but did not notice the question did not mention _glad_.